# In which webgl shader do I convert array to image

Tags: webgl, shader

I'm reading a z-stack of 16-bit images into javascript (i.e. an array of images). I'm new to webgl shaders and I'm having problems with how to loop over the array.

I hope to put the whole variable-length list of images, up to hundreds, onto the GPU. Then, with each change in z-stack, the gpu will render the new image. Currently, I have the following:

```
<script id="shader-vertex" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute float a_fluxes;
varying float v_flux;
attribute vec2 a_position;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main() {
    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
    gl_Position = vec4((zeroToOne * 2.0 - 1.0) * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
    v_flux = a_fluxes/256.;
}
</script>
<script id="shader-fragment" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision highp float;
varying float v_flux;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_flux, v_flux, v_flux, 1);
}
</script>
```

The 3 dimensional array of images (x, y, and z) is supposed to be converted to a 1d list going into a_fluxes.

How do I iterate over the x and y dimensions of one of the z images? Do I use a loop to iterate in the vertex shader or am I required to pass in an array of all of the possible x,y coordinates of the pixels to the vertex shader? Should I really be doing these calculations on the fragment shader?

Comment: You don't iterate over the x,y coordinates, and you wouldn't want to:  otherwise, how would the work be divided up among the GPU units? Loops aren't always easy to break apart.  OpenGL divides the work up among the units and iterates through for you.  As to how best to handle this situation, well, that's beyond my current, also-newbie experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be well-served to put the textures together into an atlas (a 2d array of images as one image), if you plan to jump between them using the GPU. WebGL doesn't support volume textures, if it did I'd recommend using a slice per image -- but instead you'll probably be best-off slicing-out windows from the UV space of a larger composite image, where each window corresponds to one of your sub-images.